# Php, include_once, absolute path, inconsistent results

Tags: php

I've found a lot of questions about `include_once` not working, but the vast majority of them -- on this site and elsewhere -- were due to people not understanding the difference between relative and absolute paths, or relative paths not working the way they expected. I'm using an absolute path, so these answers don't help me.

I have a file at `/var/www`, that we'll say is called `MYINCLUDE.php`.

In a php file inside the website, I have `include_once('/var/www/MYINCLUDE.php');`

Initially, this worked fine. But when I had to restore the VM environment, and brought these same files back to the same locations, it now gives a  `Warning: include_once(/var/www/MYINCLUDE.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include_once() (PATH_OF_FILE_CALLING_THE_INCLUDE)`

I had someone here look over my shoulder to see if I was missing something obvious; they confirm that the files are where they should be containing the lines that they should. And yes, we tried clearing the cache.

I can't figure out why the include isn't finding the file, when it did so previously without problem. Is there some other factor of how include files are found, that I'm missing?

"owner" of both files is `apache`, permissions are `775`. This is on a centOS vm running on a mac.

Comment: Is this underscore in `Warning: include_once(/var/www/MY_INCLUDE_.php):`... really there? If yes, that’s definitively your problem.

Comment: @LindaJeanne No, it’s about the underscore at the end in: `Warning: include_once(/var/www/MY_INCLUDE  >>>_<<<  .php):` in the warning message.

Comment: I goofed when I changed the filename to post it. The warning doesn't have an underscore in it -- sorry for the confusion.

Comment: is `/var` the absolute root of the volume? what does `var_dump(__DIR__, __FILE__);` display when put just before the `include` statement? `realpath('/var/www/MY_INCLUDE.php');` returns?

Comment: yes, the `var` is directly under root. i.e. `cd /` followed by `ls` will show the `var` directory. The vardump of `__FILE__` shows the file that's trying to include MYINCLUDE.php, and `__DIR__` shows the the directory that the file trying to call MYINCLUDE.php is in. (Fairly deep in the directory structure within `/var/www/html/...`) More specifically, `/var/www/html/profiles/MYPROFILE/modules/MYMODULEFOLDER/MYMODULE/file_trying_to_include_the_other.php`. Standard location for Drupal build profiles.

Comment: Thanks -- alas, I checked, and that's not the issue. (I edit in vim, and move files around on the command line, so it would be harder to slip an odd character in without noticing anyway.)